# Is the name of God associated with bris milah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, brit-milah, shemos-sacred-names

I recall learning, but have no source for, the fact that part of what is achieved by the bris milah process is a form of etching (part of?) the name of God into the makom ha'milah.

1. What is the source for the idea that the performance of a bris milah associates the name of God with the makom ha'milah?
2. Which name of God is associated?

Comment: I've heard this too but I don't remember the source.  I'll look for it tonight b'n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is Professor Elliot Wolfson's niche. He has [written copiously](https://files.nyu.edu/erw1/public/scholarship.html) on this topic including:

- [Circumcision and the Divine Name: A Study in the Transmission of Esoteric Doctrine](http://www.michtavim.com/Wolfson/02_Circumcision_and_the_Divine_Name-A_Study_in_the_Transmission_of_Esoteric_Doctrine.pdf) (PDF)
- [Circumcision, Vision of God, and Textual Interpretation: From Midrashic Trope to Mystical
  Symbol](http://www.michtavim.com/Wolfson/03_Circumcision_Vision_of_God_and_Textual_Interpretations_From_Midrashic_Trope_To_Mystical_Symbol) (PDF)

among others. To quote from one of his many sources, the midrash tanchuma parshat tzav section 14

> All of Israel who are circumcised [upon death] enter the Garden 
>   of Eden, for the Holy One, blessed be He, has placed His 
>   name in Israel so that they will enter the Garden of Eden. And 
>   what is the name and the seal which He placed 
>   in them? It is [the name] Shin-Dalet-Yod. He placed the shin in the nose, 
>   the dalet in the hand, and the yod on the [place of] circum- 
>   cision. Therefore when a Jew dies there is an appointed angel 
>   in the Garden of Eden, who receives every circumcised Jew 
>   and brings him into the Garden of Eden.

Comment: See also Midrash Tanchuma (Parshat Shemini, section 8).